# UMVUE for a function of parameter

Tags: statistics, statistical-inference

Let's say in the exponential distribution, the cdf if
$$f(x|\lambda)=\frac{1}{\lambda}\exp\left\{-\frac{x}{\lambda}\right\}$$
If we have $n$ observations: $X_1, X_2, \cdots, X_n$. Then we know since it belongs to the exponential family we have the UMVUE for $\lambda$ is
$$T({\bf X})=\sum^n_{i=1}X_i$$
And
$$E(T)=E\left(\sum^n_{i=1}X_i\right)=\sum^n_{i=1}E(X_i)=n\lambda$$
Then 
$$\hat{\lambda}_{UMVUE}=\frac{T}{n}=\bar{X}$$
Then, what if we want to find the UMVUE of $\frac{1}{\lambda}$?

Comment: About notation: As defined in this Question, $\lambda$ is the mean; often denoted $\mu.$ Then the rate is $1/\mu,$ often denoted as $\lambda.$  UMVUE for $\mu$ is $\bar X.$ UMVUE for the rate is as shown in @Momo's Answer (+1).

Comment: Use the fact that $T$ is a Gamma variable to calculate $E(1/T)$. Then adjust the lhs to get exactly $1/\lambda$ in the rhs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint:

First prove that:
$$E\left[\frac{1}{X_1+X_2}\right]=\frac{1}{\lambda}$$

Then user Rao-Blackwellization to prove that
$\frac{n-1}{\sum X_i}$ is the UMVUE

... or you can directly calculate the expectation of the UMVUE and use that is a function of $T$